# Разграничение доступа Django

Tags: python, django

я новичок в программировании, пожалуйста дайте совет. Мне нужно реализовать функционал выдачи результатов из функции для каждого авторизованного пользователя используя серию и номер паспорта, которые находятся в БД. Клиент, образно, нажимает на ссылку личного кабинета, логинится, и данные этого пользователя из БД передаются в функцию, затем функция обрабатывает его запрос и выдает результат. Вся проблема в том как именно передать данные именно этого человека. Пожалуйста, укажите направление в котором копать.

Comment: request.user - хранит текущую информацию о пользователе. (к примеру request.user.username выведет имя текущего пользователя на сайте или request.user.is_authenticated - вернёт True или False, в зависимости от того, авторизован ли пользователь или нет.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```py
def profile(request):
    usr_id = request.user.id # Получите id пользователя
    # дальше делайте что хотите
```

Не забудьте проверить пользователя иначе получите ошибку, например так:

```py
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    usr_id = request.user.id # Получите id пользователя
```